# What is the equivalent of a Button Click in DevExpress?

Tags: wpf, devexpress

In WPF, a button and a click event is:

```
<Button Click="Btn_Click" />

private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ....
}
```

In DevExpress, according to the [documentation](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfBarsBarItem_ItemClicktopic), I would guess the equivalent would be:

```
<dxb:BarButtonItem ItemClick="Btn_Click" />

private event ItemClickEventHandler Btn_Click(Item sender, RoutedEvent e)
{
   ....
}
```

But it is not compiling. I would guess it is very easy but I cannot find any example in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of the handler should be a `ItemClickEventArgs`:

```
private void Btn_Click(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: I'm porting my XAML to DevExpress XAML, does that mean all the event handler and parameters have to be changed, or does the original event handler still work?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. "Item" does not exist in the current context, "sender", ) expected, and "ItemClickEventArgs" could not be found.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the other mistakes in your code so I didn't fix them... the first parameter must be `object`, and the return type should be `void`. What you saw in the documentation is the declaration of the event, not the signature of the handler...